# Where can I find table of CentOS distributions versions and corresponding Linux kernel versions?

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, version

There is a somewhat related [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/290039/where-can-i-find-an-online-list-of-centos-packages-and-their-versions) but both questions are still different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS#CentOS_releases

It will be found in a table under section 3: Versioning and releases

Comment: It is hidden by default. Weird. Had to click to show it. Thanks